# Socket return the same value for every new process

Tags: c, sockets, networking, file-descriptor

I have a program calling `listenfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)` which return a file descriptor. Then I tried to open the same program in different terminals, so that they can interact with each on `127.0.0.1` but different port.

However, when I open 4 terminals at the same time and check the `listenfd`, they all return 1. So only one out of 4 terminals can run properly and the other will return error on `Address already in use` when I tried to bind the listenfd to 127.0.0.1 with unique port number.

How can I make `socket` to return different file descriptor on different processes?

Thanks

Comment: The file-descriptors are *per process*. You don't worry that e.g. `STDIN_FILENO` is `0` in all processes?

Comment: Oh.. You are right. So is there any solutions for this?

Comment: No "solution", because it's not a problem. Think of file-descriptors as indexes into an array, an array that is unique in each process. If you have any other array (say `int array[ARRAY_SIZE];`) would you worry that index `2` is the same if you run your program twice?

Comment: Only one socket can listen at a given address. If you are getting this error, you are not using different ports. (An address is a triple of IP/port/protocol). Show how you bind the address.

Comment: Oh problem solved. You are right, I forgot to update the port number for each process. Thank you very much!

Comment: I learnt an important concept from @JoachimPileborg though lol

Comment: While all the data above is correct, I'd like to add a tiny bit here - OS usually assigns file descriptors in the order they are opened, starting with 1 and incrementing every time a new descriptor is open. Since the first 3 descriptors available to any program are STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR (1, 2 and 3) I am surprised to see your socket descriptor is 1. Are you closing standard descriptors?